# How to pass XIB file data in ViewController file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xib

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    id object = [DATA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"CELL^1:%@",object);

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {

        NSMutableArray *dict = (NSMutableArray *)object;
        PartyCodeTF= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[ dict  objectAtIndex:0]];
        PartyNameTF= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[ dict  objectAtIndex:1]];
        PartySNameTF= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[ dict  objectAtIndex:2]];
        OpeningTF= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[ dict  objectAtIndex:3]];
        ContactNoTF= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[ dict  objectAtIndex:4]];

    }
    PartyVC *loading=[[PartyVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"PartyVC" bundle:nil];
    loading.delegate=self; // protocol listener
    loading.PartyCode= PartyCodeTF;
    loading.PartyName= PartyNameTF;
    loading.Opening =OpeningTF;
    loading.PartySName=PartySNameTF;
    loading.ContactNo=ContactNoTF;
    loading.Track_1=@"2";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:loading animated:YES];
    [self performSelector:@selector(closeButton_Click:) withObject:self];
}
```

my `XIB` file contain a `UITableview`.
when click on `UITableviewCell` close xib file and data pass to `PartyVC` `textfields`. `self.navigationController` pushViewController gives error 
for property

> navigationController not found.

please help me... thank in advance.

Comment: Does your tableViewController has a embedded NavigationController to it ??

Comment: in my project use programmatic NavigationController which defines in AppDelegate file

Comment: @JatinRBKorat I think problem seems in your last line. The last line you have written is for which purpose? Move the last line before PartyVC *loading=[[PartyVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"PartyVC" bundle:nil]; Then try to compile.

Comment: @JatinRB Korat: Have you use the navigation controller to show the table viewController? or you are just preset it?

Comment: What gets printed if you put `NSLog(@"Navigation controller: %@, new controller: %@", self.navigationController, loading);` immediately before pushing `loading`?